# Global symbol "%s" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I have a problem with subroutine call and printing to debug file if it contains variable `$ruleRegExp`.

I run the script with these params:

```
./script --help --input=input --output=vystup --format=regulars
```

Exactly it says:

```
Global symbol "$ruleRegEx" requires explicit package name at ./script line 68.
Global symbol "$ruleRegEx" requires explicit package name at ./script line 69.
Execution of ./script aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I tried to figured out where is the problem and read forum but I haven't found a sigle question with this problem.

I write comments in my national language so dont pay attention to comments - the lines of code, which I think are related to this errors have comments of UPPER CASES.

My whole code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Fcntl;

# použité proměné
my $help; # pro nastavení parametru help
my $br; # pro nastavení parametru br




my $formatFile;
my $inputFile;
my $outputFile;
my $string; #řetězec načtený ze vstupního souboru
my $ruleRegEX; #DECLARED HERE
my $ruleConsequence; #řetězec, definuje obsah tagu pro daný reg. výraz

#použité funkce
sub readInput;
sub readRule;

GetOptions (
    "help"      => \$help,
    "br"        => \$br,
    "format=s"    => \$formatFile,
    "input=s"     => \$inputFile,
    "output=s"    => \$outputFile
);

#checkParams()

print "Help = $help\n";
print "br = $br\n";
print "format = $formatFile\n";
print "input = $inputFile\n";
print "output = $outputFile\n";

#Debugovací soubor pro kontrolní výpisy
sysopen DEBUG, "Debug", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT or die "Debug soubor se nepodařilo otevřít. $!\n";
    print DEBUG "Debug: Debug soubor otevřen.\n";

#otevře formátovací soubor pro čtení, převádí jeho vstup do utf8 a pokud se otevření nepovede vrací chybové hlášení
open FORMAT, "$formatFile" or die "Formátovací soubor se nepodařilo otevřít. $!\n";
print DEBUG "Debug: Formátovací soubor otevřen.\n";

#otevře vstupní soubor
if ($inputFile) {
    open STDIN, "<$inputFile" or die "Vstupní soubor se nepodařilo otevřít. $!\n";
    print DEBUG "Debug: Vstupní soubor otevřen.\n";
}

#otevře výstupní soubor, pokud neexistuje vytvoří jej.
if ($outputFile) {
    sysopen STDOUT, "$outputFile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT or die "Výstupní soubor se nepodařilo otevřít. $!\n";
    print DEBUG "Debug: Výstupní soubor otevřen.\n";
    #otestovat úspěch zápisu
    print STDOUT "Debug: Pokusný zápis.\n" 
}


readInput ($string); #načte vstup
print DEBUG "Debug: Vstup:\"$string\"\n";

#načte z formátovacího souboru jedno pravidlo do proměnných ruleRegEx a ruleConsequence
readRule($ruleRegEx, $ruleConsequence); #USED HERE
print DEBUG "Debug: ruleRegEx = \"$ruleRegEx\"\n"; #AND HERE

#useRule();



sub checkParams {
    my ( $help, $br, $formatFile, $inputFile, $outputFile) = @_;
}

# Funkce pro načtení vstupu ze vstupního souboru
#$_[0] = proměnná, do které se bude načtený vstup zapisovat

sub readInput($$) {
    local $/ = undef;
    $_[0] = <STDIN>;
    print DEBUG "Debug: načten vstup:\n";
}

#Funkce pro načtení jednotlivých částí jednoho pravidla z formátovacího souboru.
#$_[0] - rexulární výraz
#$_[1] - definice vlastností tagu
sub readRule($$) {
    my $rule = <FORMAT>;
    my $divider = "\t";
    my $index = index($rule, $divider);
    print DEBUG "Debug: \$index = \"$index\"";
    $_[0] = substr $rule, 0, $index-1;

}
```

Comment: In addition to the `use strict;` at the top, you'll also want `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 4):

In your declaration of `$ruleRegEx` you accidentally capitalized the letter x, you have actually declared the variable `$ruleRegEX`.

Note also that you might want to `use utf8` if your source file includes unicode characters.

**Edit**: the CPAN module [`utf8::all`](http://metacpan.org/module/utf8%3a%3aall) is as close to a unicode silver bullet as you can get, so you might prefer that.

Comment: Glad to help. Here on SO upvotes and accepts are the usual way to thank people who help you. Cheers, and welcome to SO.

Comment: Adding `use utf8;` only half fixes the problem. You'll get Wide Character errors. See my answer for the full fix.

Comment: ikegami is right. I normally only need unicode handling for web programming, sso the output goes to the browser; for more typical IO you will need to do that. Ikegami shows the normal usage, but you might just try `use uft8::all` which does just about everything you need for unicode, by default. There is no silver bullet, but this is close.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration names the variable

```
$ruleRegEX
```

but you use

```
$ruleRegEx
```

Note the case mismatch.

---

Also, you claim your source file contains `ě`, but that character doesn't exist in [iso-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), and you didn't use `use utf8;` to indicate the source file is encoded using UTF-8. As far as Perl is concerned, your source does not contain `ě`.

You should have the following unconditionally:

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
```

And you should have the following if the source file is encoded using UTF-8:

```
use utf8;
```

If your file isn't encoded using io-8859-1 or UTF-8, you should convert it to UTF-8 since Perl only accepts source code in those two encodings.